# Install ruby with asdf on MacOS via Homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, asdf

I recently wanted to install a different Version of ruby and Rails on MacOS Big Sur 11.5 Beta. I Installed asdf via Homebrew. I wanted to run rails server but got the Message:

```
No preset version installed for command ruby
Please install a version by running one of the following:

asdf install ruby 3.0.2

or add one of the following versions in your config file at /Users/philippkorn/.tool-versions
ruby 3.0.1
```

When I try to run any asdf install ruby command (i.e. `asdf install ruby latest`) I get the following error message:

```
~ $ asdf install ruby latest                                                                                                                                                            (base)
Version not found
```

I tried reinstalling asdf with homebrew but the error persists...

Comment: edit I'm using fish shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am facing same situation. It seems to be fixed soon.

https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/issues/239

Edit `~/.asdf/plugins/ruby/bin/install` and apply [this patch](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/pull/240/files) then the problem is fixed for me.

```
-  if [[ -n "$matching_version" ]]; then
+  if [[ -z "$matching_version" ]]; then
```

Comment: Worked for me as well, thank you!

Comment: So glad I found this. Thanks so much!

Comment: you saved me! Thanks!